# Infinite scroll bug, repeating next 10 records instead of populating more

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am not using the INFINITE SCROLL plugin.

I have about 545 records in the database and I want to display them 10 at a time for now..(testing purposes)

The first 10 records showing up perfectly and when I scroll down it pulls up the next new 10 records also. Unfortunately it is repeating those next new 10 records about 10 times.

Instead of repeating the new 10 records, I want it to pull up the next 10 additional records, and the next 10 and next 10 etc... every time I scroll down to the bottom of the page.

**MY PHP & JQUERY**

```
$stmt = $db -> query ('SELECT * FROM course LIMIT 0,10');
            $count = $db -> query ('SELECT * FROM Course');
            $nbr = $count->rowCount();
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var load = 0;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop()== jQuery(document).height()-jQuery(window).height())
            {
               load++;
                jQuery.post("ajax.php", {load:load}, function(data){
                    jQuery('.wrap').append(data);
                })
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**My Ajax.php FILE**

```
$load = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST["load"]))*10;

$query = $db -> query ("SELECT * FROM course LIMIT ".$load.",10 ");

while($row = $query->fetch()) {
?>
```

Comment: Instead of the whole `htmlentities(strip_tags())` rigmarole, you could just do `(int) $_POST['load'];` You also should echo out your Ajax.php query to see what the `$load` variable is on scroll; my guess is that's where it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are already loading when you scroll down.
So add a variable that keeps track if you are loading or not:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var isLoading = false;
        var load = 0;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if(!isLoading && jQuery(window).scrollTop()== jQuery(document).height()-jQuery(window).height())
            {
                isLoading = true;
                load++;
                jQuery.post("ajax.php", {load:load}, function(data){
                    jQuery('.wrap').append(data);
                }).always(function() {

                    isLoading = false;

                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but I am still having the same issue when adding the isLoading Variable.